# Setting the GLKView renderbuffer size

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing an iPad OpenGL ES 2.0 application and require a backing frame buffer of 1024x768.  I use GLKView and iOS 5.1 to manage creation of backend frame/render buffers (using code from the autogenerated OpenGL Game template provided by XCode).  I get acceptable performance on iPad2, and life is good.

However, during testing I got my hands on a iPad 3 with Retina display, and when my application is recompiled/installed to the iPad3, the backend frame/render buffers are running at 2048x1536, and this is crippling my performance.

Now for my questions:

1) How do I force the GLKView autogenerated frame buffer to default to 1024x768 instead of 2048x1536.

Bonus question:

2) How come I'm not getting the x2 scaling button?  Is this because I've recompiled the app with the iPad3 attached, and Xcode doing some behind the scenes modifications?  If I only compile the app with my iPad2 attached and submit the application to the AppStore, will the end user running an iPad3 actually get the x2 scaling button then?

Comment: Why are you expecting a x2 scaling button at all?

Comment: Further on Till's comment; I think the x2 scaling button you're thinking of is that displayed on an iPad when it runs an iPhone application? You should never see it when running an iPad application on an iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to force a `GLKView` not to use full retina resolution, just set the `contentScaleFactor` to `1.0`.

The `contentScaleFactor` is the number of pixels per point. All iPads have a screen resolution of 1024x768 points so a full-screen view with a content scale factor of 1.0 will have 1024x768 pixels. The scale factor will otherwise default to 2.0 on a retina device and 1.0 otherwise.

Comment: Solved my problem with GLKView - the frame was a bit over 2048 in one dimension, was getting "Failed to make complete framebuffer object" console errors. It never occurred to be that retain would inflate the internal buffer size > 4096.